# Drop factor levels once a category is reached in longitudinal data

Tags: r

I have a data frame of recorded data that a longitudinal structure as this:

```
 id          event
1   1   registration
2   1     inspection
3   1     inspection
4   1 deregistration
5   2   registration
6   2     inspection
7   2 deregistration
8   2     inspection
9   3   registration
10  3 deregistration
11  3     inspection
12  3     inspection
13  4   registration
14  4     inspection
15  4     inspection
16  4 deregistration
```

I need to drop the levels that are after one category. Essentially I need to drop the subsequent levels of `event` that are after the category `deregistration`. The data frame should look like this:

```
   id          event
1   1   registration
2   1     inspection
3   1     inspection
4   1 deregistration
5   2   registration
6   2     inspection
7   2 deregistration
8   3   registration
9   3 deregistration
10  4   registration
11  4     inspection
12  4     inspection
13  4 deregistration
```

This is de code cor generating `df`

```
df = data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
                  event = as.factor(c("registration", "inspection", "inspection", "deregistration",
                                  "registration", "inspection", "deregistration", "inspection",
                                  "registration", "deregistration","inspection", "inspection",
                                  "registration", "inspection", "inspection", "deregistration")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(post.deregistration = cumsum(event == "deregistration")) %>%
  mutate(drop = cumsum(post.deregistration) > 1) %>%
  filter(!drop) %>% select(-c(post.deregistration, drop))

# A tibble: 13 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
      id          event
   <int>         <fctr>
 1     1   registration
 2     1     inspection
 3     1     inspection
 4     1 deregistration
 5     2   registration
 6     2     inspection
 7     2 deregistration
 8     3   registration
 9     3 deregistration
10     4   registration
11     4     inspection
12     4     inspection
13     4 deregistration
```

Comment: Yes it does. Many thanks @Z.Lin. I did not know `cumsum()` could be used in that way but it seems very useful.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Deregistration = ifelse(event == "deregistration", 1, NA)) %>%
  fill(Deregistration, .direction = "up") %>%
  drop_na(Deregistration) %>%
  select(-Deregistration)

df2
# A tibble: 13 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
      id          event
   <int>         <fctr>
 1     1   registration
 2     1     inspection
 3     1     inspection
 4     1 deregistration
 5     2   registration
 6     2     inspection
 7     2 deregistration
 8     3   registration
 9     3 deregistration
10     4   registration
11     4     inspection
12     4     inspection
13     4 deregistration
```